# Calling library function eats up the stack. Why?

Tags: delphi, crash, stack, delphi-xe3

Sorry, probably this one is also easy for Delphi programmers, but it is not for me. I have a library function I am calling, and basically it eats my stack. It does so by pushing the variables for the function into the stack, but somehow Delphi does not pop them from the stack. So after the function ends I land in nowhere. Funny enough i can just do "pop eax" as many as I have parameters, and it works. Can anyone shed light on whats happening? 
The working code goes like this:

```
function LoadIntoMemory(sdiPath: String): Integer;
var
   retValue: Integer;
begin
  retValue := file_open(PAnsichar(AnsiString(sdiPath)), @filedata, @filedatasize);
   asm
     pop eax
     pop eax
     pop eax
   end;
 end;
```

As said, without popping from the stack it crashes.

The function itself is from a C DLL, linked statically like this:

```
function file_open (filename: PAnsichar; filedata: PPAnsichar; filedatasize: PLongInt): Integer; stdcall; external  'libLib';
```

linking dynamically does not alter the behaviour.

Comment: I would try "cdecl". Not sure it will help, because the order of the variables will change.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have it now. Sorry for probably easy RTFM questions. I should have used cdecl; instead of stdcall. Only wished all these Delphi DLL linking tutorials would have mentioned it somewhere.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Procedures_and_Functions

Answer (score 0):

This is a calling convention mis-match. The callee is cdecl and the caller uses stdcall. The key difference is who cleans the stack. For stdcall it is the callee and for cdecl it is the caller.

This explains what you have observed. The actual function is cdecl. And so the does not clean the stack. But your calling code believes the function is stdcall and so expects the callee to clean the stack. Thus, neither side cleans it.

More details here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions